# Calculating Averages from a text file in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a text file that reads:

```
D:2013:09:1:H:30:P:992:R:29:T:39:W:28:D:2013:09:2:P:1009:T:3 
3:D:2013:09:3:H:31:P:1001:T:33:W:15:D:2013:09:4:H:20:R:5:T:7 
1:W:31:D:2013:09:5:P:991:T:36:D:2013:09:6:H:74:P:1005:R:95:T 
:82:W:34:D:2013:09:7:P:1000:T:55:W:30:D:2013:09:8:H:55:P:982 
:T:49:W:22:D:2013:09:9:H:73:P:997:T:58:W:27:D:2013:09:10:H:5 
2:P:993:D:2013:09:11:H:27:P:1010:R:32:W:26:D:2013:09:12:H:71 
:P:1018:R:91:T:74:W:6:D:2013:09:13:H:89:P:996:R:95:T:75:W:26 
:D:2013:09:14:P:1013:R:10:W:13:D:2013:09:15:P:1014:T:66:W:21 
:D:2013:09:16:P:1010:R:25:T:21:W:30:D:2013:09:17:P:1007:D:20 
13:09:18:P:992:R:59:W:29:D:2013:09:19:T:80:W:10:D:2013:09:20 
:D:2013:09:21:P:985:T:64:W:18:D:2013:09:22:H:32:P:1007:W:10: 
D:2013:09:23:H:60:P:1009:T:48:W:15:D:2013:09:24:P:986:T:62:D 
:2013:09:25:T:48:D:2013:09:26:D:2013:09:27:H:57:P:986:R:99:T 
:56:W:23:D:2013:09:28:P:996:W:32:D:2013:09:29:P:1018:T:47:D: 
2013:09:30:H:77:T:73:W:7:************************************
```

a full set of data is D:2013:09:1:H:30:P:992:R:29:T:39:W:28

it can be seen that all data items are separated by colons (‘:’). The letters D, H, P, R, T, W stand for Date, Humidity, Pressure, Rainfall, Temperature and Windspeed, respectively

(EDIT: ON DAYS WHEN THERE ISN'T A READING ON THE FILE IT MEANS IT WAS 0 FOR THAT DAY.)

after separating the data, how do i format the data into a 2 dimensional array that is able to calculate the averages of each data item?

My code at the moment is

```
using (StreamReader Data = new StreamReader("Telemetry_Data.txt")) //Reads Text From File
{
    String line = Data.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    char[] SeprateData = { 'D', 'H', 'P', 'R', 'T', 'W', ':' };
    string[] stringData = line.Split(SeprateData);

    foreach (string ss in stringData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ss);
    }
```

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't create a multidimensional array. I'd create a model object that contains the necessary properties (Date, Humidity, Pressure etc) and then create a list of those models by splitting the data on spaces.

Comment: Do you want us to make the code for you, or do you have a **specific** problem?

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere in there.

Comment: Does each set of data start with D? If so split on that first and then parse each string into the desired parts.  Otherwise you'll have to step through the characters to separate the data up.

Comment: @AndrewArnold: I added the `?` so the question (which was already there) could be more visibly identified.

Comment: I would use regexes to read data and put in a model and then do whatever is needed.

Comment: You probably want to use [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to create an expandable array of data values, since you do not know how many values you will have to begin with.

Comment: You're also going to run into problems because you're splitting data "sets" across lines and not dealing with that. For example, on your first line, an entire number gets split by the carriage-return and/or line-feed. `3\r\n3` isn't a parsable number.

Comment: @DavidRTribble OP, most probably, doesn't want to use `java.util.ArrayList` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of gross, but should get you down the correct path.

```
var humidity = Regex.Matches(line, "H:(?<humidity>[0-9]+?):").Cast<Match>().ToArray().Average(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Groups["humidity"].Value));
```

I did notice that your data set has 30 dates, but only 14 humidity readings